# Stop service at uninstall on Win 7 with UAC on from WIX

Tags: wix, windows-services, installation, wix3

How can i stop my service at uninstall in Win7 or Vista with UAC on from WIX?
When i uninstall my service from Control Panel in Win7 or Vista with UAC on I always get "File is in use message". How can i stop it so that message won't appear?
I have this code in Wix:

```
     <ServiceInstall Id='MyServiceInstall' DisplayName='OnPremises Gateway' Name='OPGatewayService'
  ErrorControl='normal' Start='auto' Type='ownProcess' Vital='yes' Account='NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService'   />
          <ServiceControl Id="StartOPGatewayServiceControl" Name="OPGatewayService" Wait="no" Start="install"  />
          <ServiceControl Id="StopOPGatewayServiceControl" Name="OPGatewayService" Stop="both" Wait="yes" Remove="uninstall"/>
```

Thank you,
Adriana

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After investigating more about this, the solution is to use a program at uninstall (like Uninstall.exe) which requires admin rights from user before any actions that imply system changes (like stop service). And from that program run MsiExec.exe /X[MsiProductId]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the "File in use" detection is early. Check out the MSI SDK documentation about their interaction: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372466(VS.85).aspx